# PowerBI Date hierarchy with Week Number

Tags: powerbi, week-number

Date Hierarchy in PowerBI:

How can I create manually a date hierarchy to contain week number?
Here's what I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

but with weeknumber included in this hierarchy.

Comment: If you have a separate date table with the required columns, you can just create the hierarchy **manually** in the same way as you would do with other dimensions in the visuals, e.g. [year], [month], [week] just add/stack them to the x-axis field.